# Differentiating between mass & individual status updates (mobile app)?

Tags: user-expectation, dropdown, status, choices

We are doing an app on delivering parcels to different areas and the status would get updated as the parcels reach certain points. As per the image below, all items (6 lines) are in the same group. In a normal / usual case, the status update would be for all (hence the dropdown), however, there may be cases wherein one item may be missing (or damaged, etc.). Hence, we also like the ability to update each item's status individually.

[image]

[image]

Now my worry is that there are 2 ways of updating it, one (1) is via the mass update (dropdown) and two (2) is when you click the status, an overlay with the different types of status will appear.

Will this confuse the user? Is this common practice?

Comment: Did you checked it with user or what results shows in your user testing? (1) The bottom "status type drop-down" is confusing and I am not sure what is the use of it in bottom location. Does that mean, user filtered it to see "status type 1"? Then in that case, top "Status" should be a link. (2) Correct me if I am wrong, can you elaborate how the status will be update automatically once it reach to certain points? or, user will update the status once reach to certain point? (3) the bottom "update status" will be enable if you change any statuses from Status column. Once click to "update status"

Comment: Once click to "update status" it should go disable with a short conformation message and vanished after 5 seconds. (4) If the product is missing / damaged, from the group list user can update status from the status column, with some "note" or "reason" to submit or to maintained record purpose. (5) From 1st image, you said "all items (6 lines) are in the same group", are you also showing a group name? because without it, it is little difficult to understand where the user is.

Answer (score 1):

I do think this will confuse the user as there are two very different ways to do the same thing (change status type).

I think you should give the whole group its **own** "Group Status". It should act in the same way setting a single item's status would, but would be **much** cleaner and a bit more intuitive for the user. Maybe something like this:

[image: Mass Update]

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it right now, it is confusing that when you change the General Status all of them are updated (as if the user had clicked one by one each element and changed its value).

This might bring some strange behaviour:

```
#A Status1
#B Status1
#C Status2
#D Status1
```

changing #General to Status2 will result in

```
#A Status2
#B Status2
#C Status2
#D Status2
```

if you change again #General to Status3, what is the result?

```
#A Status3
#B Status3
#C Status3 <--
#D Status3
```

or

```
#A Status3
#B Status3
#C Status2 <--
#D Status3
```

I would prevent the General status modifying each individual status:

[image: status]

In this example you can set each element to whatever status you want. But there is an extra option which is "default".

**When you assign default value to an element, the value selected in the Default section will apply to it**. However, when you change that Default section (below) it won't change the option selected in each element (the option selected will remain "default", although now that default implies other status).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty close to the best solution for this in my opinion. I like the popup that has various radio buttons that lets the user change the status quickly.

We can/should use the same popup for the bulk scenario as well, the user selects the various items using the check box or by long tap on the item and once he selects more than two items he sees a button on the top right that says change status. Tapping which should open the same popup and let the user choose the status of the selected orders at once. It doesn't have to be everything in the group but those orders that need the bulk action.

This way the mechanics stay the same, the interface stays the same and it is a win win situation. To further make it error prone we can add a confirmation that asks the user for confirmation just in case of bulk change.